# Scala - Nested loops, for-comprehension and type of the final iteration

Tags: scala, loops

I'm relatively new to scala and made some really simple programs succesfully.
However, now that I'am trying some real world problem resolution, things are getting a little bit harder...

I want to read some files into 'Configuration' objects, using various 'FileTypeReader' subtypes that can 'accept' certain files (one for each FileTypeReader subtype) and return an Option[Configuration] if it can extract a configuration from it.

I'm trying to avoid the imperative style and wrote, for exemple, something like this (using scala-io, scaladoc for Path here http://jesseeichar.github.com/scala-io-doc/0.3.0/api/index.html#scalax.file.Path ) :

```
(...)
trait FileTypeReader {
   import scalax.file.Path
   def accept(aPath : Path) : Option[Configuration]
}
var readers : List[FileTypeReader] = ...// list of concrete readers
var configurations = for (
          nextPath <- Path(someFolder).children();
          reader <- readers
      ) yield reader.accept(nextPath);
(...)
```

Of course, that does not work, for-comprehensions return a collection of the first generator type (here, some IterablePathSet).

Since I tried many variant and feel like running in circle, I beg for you advices on that matter to solve my - trivial ? - problem with elegance ! :)

Many thanks in advance,

sni.

Comment: It's a bit difficult unless you tell us what the types of the elements in the comprehension are - i.e. what does `children()` return, what is `readers`. REPL examples are extremely useful for asking scala questions as they can be REPLicated

Comment: I edited my question to be clearer !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your problem is that you have a `Set[Path]` and want to yield a `List[Option[Configuration]]`. As written, `configurations` will be a `Set[Option[Configuration]]`. To change this to a `List`, use the `toList` method i.e.

```
val configurations = (for {
    nextPath <- Path(someFolder).children
    reader   <- readers
  } yield reader.accept(nextPath) ).toList
```

or, change the type of the generator itself:

```
val configurations = for {
    nextPath <- Path(someFolder).children.toList
    reader   <- readers
  } yield reader.accept(nextPath)
```

You probably actually want to get a `List[Configuration]`, which you can do elegantly since `Option` is a monad:

```
val configurations = for {
    nextPath <- Path(someFolder).children.toList
    reader   <- readers
    conf     <- reader.accept(nextPath)
  } yield conf
```

Comment: Well Luigi, that's great and exactly what I want! However, can anybody explain me why I got : "No implicit view available from ScalaObject => scala.collection.TraversableOnce[B]" when I try 'configurations.flatten' with your first solution WITHOUT the toList, and why it works perfectly fine when I add it ?

Comment: I don't know; it should work (`Set(Some(1), None).flatten` compiles). You're not using an ancient version of Scala, pre 2.8, are you? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895069/how-to-flatten-list-of-options-using-higher-order-functions

Comment: No, 2.9.1 with sbt 0.11.2 and scala.io 0.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to find the *first* configuration that it can extract? If not, what happens if multiple configurations are returned?

In the first case, I'd just get the result of the for-comprehension and call `find` on it, which will return an `Option`.

Comment: Hello Daniel, well no, I want an Iterable of ALL configurations (hence my var name) found !