# What does flatMap do exactly?

Tags: scala, flatmap

For a coding assignment for school I have to do stuff with flatmap but I have absolutely no idea what it does and I've read a couple pages online and read in my textbook but I still have no true understanding of what it does. I know what map does but for some reason it's hard for me to wrap my head around flatmap. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Just to add some more information- when I look at examples online I DO see how flatmap returns something different from map. But what is flatmap actually doing when its being called on something? How does flatmap actually work? What is it doing before it returns the result?

Comment: It's not a StackOverflow's type of question

Comment: flatmap = map+flatten

Comment: What type of question is it then?

Comment: You should do research of your own before asking question since `flatMap` is easily the most used functional programming idiom and there are literally thousands of resources out there. Good start would be to see how it's actually implemented instead of reading through abstract illustration of what it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functors define map which have type

```
trait Functor[F[_]] {
    def map[A, B](f: A => B)(v: F[A]): F[B]
}
```

Monads are functors which support two additional operations:

```
trait Monad[M[_]] extends Functor[M] {
    def pure[A](v: A): M[A]
    def join[A](m: M[M[A]]): M[A]
}
```

Join flattens nested values e.g. if `m` is `List` then `join` has type

```
def joinList[A](l: List[List[A]]): List[A]
```

If you have a monad `m` and you `map` over it, what happens if `b` is the same monadic type? For example:

```
def replicate[A](i: Int, value: A): List[A] = ???
val f = new Functor[List] {
    def map[A, B](f: A => B)(v: List[A]) = v.map(f)
}
```

then

```
f.map(x => replicate(x, x))(List(1,2,3)) == List(List(1), List(2,2), List(3,3,3))
```

This has type `List[List[Int]]` while the input is a `List[Int]`. It's fairly common with a chain of operations to want each step to return the same input type. Since `List` can also be made into a monad, you can easily create such a list using `join`:

```
listMonad.join(List(List(1), List(2,2), List(3,3,3))) == List(1,2,2,3,3,3)
```

Now you might want to write a function to combine these two operations into one:

```
trait Monad[M] {
   def flatMap[A, B](f: A => M[B])(m: M[A]): M[B] = join(map(f)(m))
}
```

then you can simply do:

```
listMonad.flatMap(List(1,2,3), x => replicate(x, x)) == List(1,2,2,3,3,3)
```

Exactly what `flatMap` does depends on the monad type constructor `M` (`List` in this example) since it depends on `map` and `join`.

Comment: I cannot imagine this talk of Monads will help the original poster.

Comment: @alper - How can you explain `flatMap` without talking about monads? The fact they accepted this answer indicates they did find it helpful.

Comment: I think it's needlessly obscurantist since monads themselves are not explained properly anywhere either.

Comment: Case in point, here's the reverse definition: http://chris.eidhof.nl/post/monads-in-swift/

Comment: @alper - That link does not explain what `flatMap` does at all. This answer explains what `Monad`s are (functors with two extra operations `pure` and `join`) then defines `flatMap` in terms of two operations that `Monad` supports (`map` and `join`). The only thing missing is the monad laws which your link makes no mention of either.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an analogy.

Imagine you have a big bag filled with shopping vouchers for cartons of eggs. If you have a function which is "use the voucher to buy a carton of eggs" and you called `bigBagOfVouchers.map(buyCartonOfEggs)`, you'd have a bag of cartons of eggs.

However, if you called `bigBagOfVouchers.flatMap(buyCartonOfEggs)`, you'd have a bag of eggs - without any cartons.

`flatMap` flattens the result by one level. What might have been `Bag[Carton[Egg]]` is now `Bag[Egg]`.

Comment: Is this right?  I always thought `flatMap` required the 'inner' monad to be exactly the same type as the 'outer' monad.  Though, I guess you might say that it would work if both `Bag` and `Carton` were `Iterable`.

Comment: basically .flatMap is nothing but .map(x => something(x)).flatten . Am i right in my assumption?

Comment: That's right. Although, `flatten` didn't exist until v2.8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895069/how-to-flatten-list-of-options-using-higher-order-functions

Answer (score 0):

In reactive programming, you often come into the situation in which you need to use **flatMap** to convert *Future[Future[List]]* to *Future[List]*. For example, you have two functions: *get* Users from database and *process* retrieved Users; and both  return *Future[List[User]]*. If you apply **map** to *get* and *process*, the result will be *Future[Future[List[User]]]* which does not make any sense. Instead, you should use flatMap:

```
def main(): Future[List[User]] = getUsers flatMap processUsers    
def getUsers: Future[List[User]]
def processUsers(users: List[User]): Future[List[User]]
```